# How to "modify" a closure

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, closures, php-7

I'm making a class to add metaboxes to Wordpress extending functionality of Metabox.io.

Now you often have metaboxes with the same attributes (for example for the same post type). I want to group these so you don't have to duplicate those attributes.

I have a function `add()` which simply adds a metabox.

Now I want the `group()` method to do the following:

```
$manager->group([
    'post_types' =>'page',
], function() use ($manager) {

    $manager->add('metaboxfromgroup', [
        'title'      => __( 'Metabox added from group!', 'textdomain' ),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'fields'     => [
            [
                'name'  => __( 'Here is a field', 'textdomain' ),
                'id'    => 'fname',
                'type'  => 'text',
            ],
        ]
    ]);

});
```

So my `group()` method accepts an array of attributes, which need to be added to the array of attributes of every single `add()` in the Closure.

Laravel does this really beautifully with Routes, looks something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

This is my Metabox manager class

```
namespace Vendor\Lib;

use Vendor\App\Config as Config;

final class Metabox {

    /** @var string */
    protected $prefix;

    /** @var array */
    static private $metaboxes = [];

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new Metabox();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    /**
     * Metabox constructor.
     *
     * @param string $prefix
     */
    private function __construct() {
        $this->prefix = Config::get('metabox.prefix');
    }

    /**
     * Add a new metabox.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function add( $id, array $attributes ) {
        $attributes['id'] = $id;

        array_walk_recursive( $attributes, function ( &$value, $key ) {
            if (
                $key === 'id'
                && substr( $value, 0, strlen( $this->prefix ) ) !== $this->prefix
            ) {
                $value = $this->prefix . $value; // auto prefix
            }
        } );

        self::$metaboxes[] = $attributes;
    }

    public function group( $attributes, $function) {
        // here comes group method
    }

    /**
     * Register the metaboxes.
     */
    public function register() {
        add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', function () {
            return self::$metaboxes;
        } );
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to achieve something in Laravel or is Laravel just a showcase of what you want to achieve in WordPresss or whatever toy you're playing with?

Comment: Laravel was just an example. I want to create something similar: appending to the second parameters' array of the add function in the closure.

Comment: Manager refers to a singleton class. So currently cannot extend it.

Comment: Im not using any framework. I will share the code of my Metabox manager in one second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136016/discussion-between-melvin-koopmans-and-marco-aurelio-deleu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one suggestion. When calling the `group` method, you can store the shareable information within your class and later use it inside your `add` method.

```
final class Metabox {
    private $group = [];
    ...
}

public function group( $attributes, $function) {
    $this->group = $attributes;
    $function(); // Invoke the closure, I don't remember if this is the right way.
    $this->group = [];  // Clean up the group.
}
```

Now, for the `add` method.

```
/**
 * Add a new metabox.
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @param array $attributes
 */
public function add( $id, array $attributes ) {
    if(!empty($this->group))
       $attributes = array_merge($group, $attributes);

    $attributes['id'] = $id;

    array_walk_recursive( $attributes, function ( &$value, $key ) {
        if (
            $key === 'id'
            && substr( $value, 0, strlen( $this->prefix ) ) !== $this->prefix
        ) {
            $value = $this->prefix . $value; // auto prefix
        }
    } );

    self::$metaboxes[] = $attributes;
}
```

Sidenote: Calling array_merge with `$attributes` as your second parameter allows you to overwrite group values for just a specific add.

Comment: Aahhh damn that's smart. Why didn't I think of that, let me try this out and I'll let you know!

Comment: Works! Thanks for you help. Made some minor changes: since you do $this->group = $attributes you're setting the group variable so it's not necessary to make it empty again (with $this->group = [];). Thanks again!

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans If you call the `group` method, later make a call just to `add` (without group), it will automatically be grouped if you don't clean it up.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can remove the need to specify `use ($manager)` when calling the group method? Can I somehow inject an instance into the closure within the group method?